# Are there extensions of Hilb's and Laplace's formulas to Jacobi polynomials with $\alpha,\beta\le-1$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics, orthogonal-polynomials

In Szegő's Orthogonal Polynomials book, he gives two interesting asymptotic formulas for Jacobi polynomials with $\alpha,\beta>-1$. The first (Theorem 8.21.12, [page 197](https://books.google.com/books?id=RemVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197) is a generalization of Hilb's formula for Legendre polynomials:

Let $\alpha>-1$ and let $\beta$ be arbitrary. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{\alpha}\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{\beta}P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(\cos\theta)&=N^{-\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}{n!}(\theta/\sin\theta)^{1/2}J_{\alpha}(N\theta)\\
&+\begin{cases}
\theta^{1/2}O(n^{-3/2}) & if & cn^{-1}\leq\theta\leq\pi-\epsilon,\\
\theta^{\alpha+2}O(n^\alpha) & if  & 0<\theta\leq cn^{-1},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $N=n+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta+1)$ and $c$ and $\epsilon$ are fixed positive numbers.

A generalization of Laplace's formula for Legendre polynomials is also stated (Theorem 8.21.13, [page 197](https://books.google.com/books?id=RemVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197)):

Let $\alpha>-1, \beta>-1$. We have
\begin{align*}
P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(\cos\theta)=n^{-1/2}k(\theta)\{\cos(N\theta+\gamma)+(n\sin\theta)^{-1}O(1)\},
\end{align*}
for $cn^{-1}\leq \theta\leq \pi-cn^{-1}$. Here $c$ is a fixed positive number, $k(\theta)=\pi^{-1/2}\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{-\beta-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\gamma=-(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Szegő seems to suggest that the restrictions of $\alpha,\beta>-1$ are unnecessary after the statement of the latter result, but I haven't been able to find a reference. Are similar theorems known for $\alpha,\beta\leq -1$? Can they perhaps be derived easily with proofs similar to the case of $\alpha,\beta>-1$?